# How to construct JSON for datatables in asp.net (without MVC)

Tags: asp.net, json, datatables

I am using datatables.net library in my asp.net application which is not MVC based. My application is using WCF service to return JSON data.

CODE1 below is working fine but CODE2 which is exactly similar to (except for escaping quotes) doesn't work.  In case of CODE1 whether I comment

> "dataType": "jsonp",

or not it works both ways but in case of CODE2 it doesn't work in any case.

In case of CODE2 I get Javascript error that method or property "length" is not found or something like that.

All the examples I have seen on web are based on MVC. Please check what am I doing wrong.

**CODE1 - this code works**

*jquery*

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('#myDataTable').dataTable({
                    "serverSide": false,
                    "processing": true,
                    //"dataType": "jsonp",
                    "ajax": {
                        "url": "datatables.txt",
                    }
                });
            });
```

*datatables.txt*

```
{
       "data":[    ["Tiger Nixon","System Architect","Edinburgh","5421"],
                  ["Garrett Winters","Accountant","Tokyo","8422"],
                  ["Ashton Cox","Junior Technical Author","San Francisco","1562"]
        ]
}
```

**CODE2 - this code doesn't work**

*jquery*

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('#myDataTable').dataTable({
                    "serverSide": false,
                    "processing": true,
                    //"dataType": "jsonp",
                    "ajax": {
                        "url": "MyCode.svc/GetFileRecords",
                    }
                });

            });
```

*asp.net*

```
public string GetFileRecords()
{
return "{ \"data\":[ [\"Tiger Nixon\",\"System Architect\",\"Edinburgh\",\"5421\"], [\"Garrett Winters\",\"Accountant\",\"Tokyo\",\"8422\"], [\"Ashton Cox\",\"Junior Technical Author\",\"San Francisco\",\"1562\"] ] }";
}
```

Comment: Look at the response you're sending using your browser's debugging tools. Is it returning JSON? Or is it returning JSON inside a string? When you have doubts about what's happening, check everything end to end.

Comment: I am getting the exact same response with escape character which I have posted above under asp.net. I have solved it by using .aspx page instead of WCF service i.e. ajax calls goes to MyCode/MyPage.aspx and it prints (Response.Write) json constructed string. It's working but this is not a neat solution.